# Query by ID only when full key path is unavailable?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any way to perform a query by part of a key in datastore/firestore-in-datastore-mode?

I know the `key.id` of an object I need. Unfortunately, it is a parented object, and I do not have its `key.parent`; I thus cannot construct an actual `key` and do a `get`. Is there any way to construct a query so that it will return all objects of a given `kind` and `id`?

Comment: can you elaborate more on your question. check this document on [Store and query data in Firestore in Datastore mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/store-query-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to query for all entities with a specific key id or name as the key id or name is not indexed separately from the rest of the key.

Comment: That's really unfortunate, but thanks for the definitive answer.